# numpy package .npz component files

Tags: python, numpy

How to write data into .npz file without deleting the previous data?

I'm using python numpy package where I use the savez() to save variables.

However, each each time I saved information to the file, it delete the previous information. For instance, suppose I had

```
savez('file',a=a)
```

then if I use

```
savez('file',b=b)
```

it will delete the entire file and

```
load('file.npz').keys()
```

will only return 'b'.

Is there any option to simply "append" the variable into the file wrought delete the file? i.e. was there any way to simply add an argument like `'append=true'` so that it

```
savez('file',b=b,'append=true')
```

would not delete "a"?

Comment: Looks like [`savez`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L669) is a compressed file. This means that appending to it would require you to read from it first and then overwrite it.

Comment: `savez` can't do this. Since a `.npz` file is just a custom `.zip` archive, you _could_ work around this by saving to a `BytesIO` and the using the `zipfile` module and making sure to follow [the `.npz` specification](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html), but that's probably not a great idea. Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq No, `savez` explicitly does _not_ create a compressed file. See [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html): "The archive is not compressed." Or see the source you linked where `savez` explicitly passes `False` as the `compress` argument.

Comment: but savez() was the only way I knew to save several array properly (the other one was save() which only deal with single variables) was there any other options?

Comment: `savez` uses `save` to write each array to its own file, and then collects them into a `zip` archive.  I think it will be simpler if you use `save` directly. If you need an archive use operating system tools.

Comment: @hpaulj Why use operating system tools instead of, e.g, the `zipfile` module in the stdlib?

Comment: `savez`'s documentation explains exactly what it does, and hpaulj just explained it even more clearly. You can do the same thing yourself. Just read the docs for `zipfile` and it should be obvious how to do it, if you're not actually worried about creating a `.npz` file. Or you can just leave them as separate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.savez` creates a zip archive.  While such an archive can be opened in append mode, `savez` does not provide that option (that is, it isn't documented, and not hidden is the code either).

But `savez` creates the component files with`np.save` (technically, a few call levels down), and packs them in the `zip`.  So we can do that ourselves.

```
In [744]: import zipfile

In [746]: a=np.arange(10)
In [747]: b=np.zeros((10,10))
In [748]: np.savez('test.npz', a=a, b=b)
```

Look at the archive with `zipfile` or operating system tool:

```
In [750]: f = zipfile.ZipFile('test.npz', mode='a')  # note append mode
In [751]: f.infolist()
Out[751]: 
[<ZipInfo filename='b.npy' filemode='-rw-------' file_size=928>,
 <ZipInfo filename='a.npy' filemode='-rw-------' file_size=168>]
```

Now `save` another array, and use the `zipfile` `write`:

```
In [752]: np.save('c.npy',np.ones((2,3)))
In [753]: f.write('c.npy')
In [754]: f.infolist()
Out[754]: 
[<ZipInfo filename='b.npy' filemode='-rw-------' file_size=928>,
 <ZipInfo filename='a.npy' filemode='-rw-------' file_size=168>,
 <ZipInfo filename='c.npy' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=176>]
In [755]: f.close()
```

Test with `load`:

```
In [757]: d = np.load('test.npz')
In [758]: list(d.keys())
Out[758]: ['b', 'a', 'c']
In [759]: d['c']
Out[759]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

So `a` and `b` were added in the initial call, while `c` was added later.  A `c.npy`file still exists in the directory.  That could be deleted.

In short, `np.savez` is meant an easy way of saving multiple arrays with one call.  While using `zipfile`, it does not give direct access to all of its flexibility, such as appending or updating files.  If you want that flexibility, use `np.save` and `zipfile` directly.